# How to get the index of a tuple as it's being generated?

Tags: python, class, indexing, tuples, iteration

So, I'm instantiating a class several times using a tuple -- every tuple item is a class instance in the format

`ClassName(argument 1, ... argument n)`

Now, I'd like one of the arguments to be the index of the item in the tuple, but I don't know how to express that in Python. I tried using

`my_tuple.index(ClassName)`

but that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
tuple([ClassName(i, argument 2, ..., argument n) for i in range(however_many_you_want)])
```

This will create a list which will then be converted into a tuple.
Here, the first argument is being used as the index in the tuple.

Comment: Good answer! Note that `tuple(ClassName(i, argument 2, ..., argument n) for i in range(however_many_you_want))` (without the intermediary list) works as well: That makes the comprehension a generator.